# FTP upload in Silverlight app

Tags: file-upload, upload, ftp, silverlight-5.0, ftp-client

That would probably sound weird but in spite of all FTP protocols's weaknesses and insecureness my boss still wants me to send files to the ftp server. 
It's an out-of window app with elevated trust. So I guess there is a way.
I've tried to find any good examples but I found none.
Would you guys help me here? 
Maybe I can use sockets and would able to make it work. 
They even agreed to re-config the server to use some other port.

Comment: Just to inform you: I've implemented a rudimental ftp-client for Silverlight 5 (https://github.com/dittodhole/sharpLightFtp). But I have no idea, if it works on Mac. Ftps is currently not supported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use third-party components, such as our SecureBlackbox. If you have out-of-browser application, you should not be restricted to specific ports, so there should not be any problems in this aspect. Of course, only passive mode is supported in Silverlight, but again this is not a problem. And BTW SecureBlackbox supports both FTPS (FTP over SSL) and SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) if you later decide to switch to secure communications.

Comment: @Azgam FTPSBlackbox package price is about $140 or so.

Comment: I'm trying to use BlackBox libs. Works on WinMachine both local and remote but fails on Mac when I'm trying to create new TElSimpleFTPSClient(). Says: Attempt by security transparent method 'SBCryptoProvWin32.TElWin32ProviderInfo.AcquireProvider()' to call native code through method 'SBWinCrypt.__Global.CryptAcquireContext(UInt32 ByRef, System.String, System.String, UInt32, UInt32)' failed.  Methods must be security critical or security safe-critical to call native code.

Comment: @Agzam please use our support channels (forum and helpdesk) to get help with our products.

Comment: Can you at least tell me if there is any working ftp solutions on Silverlight using FTPSBlackBox that work on both PC and Mac? Maybe nobody ever tried to use that outside Windows and all my attempts to make it work are Sisyphean?

Comment: @Agzam Silverlight 3 and 4 don't have any OS bindings and should work on Mac. If you are trying Silverlight 5, then we probably need to make special set of SL 5 assemblies for SL/Mac. This should be discussed on our site, not here.

Comment: Common man, I have to register, besides the website opens painfully slow from where I am. And yes I installed BlackBox libraries and added references to SL5 libraries. What do you mean by special set of assemblies for Mac?